# Why mongoDB is being used in django project

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

As we know we can build great application with `django` using `postgresql` database or additional scalability and feature, sometime we use `redis`

I have notice some people using `mongodb` in their django project. My question is, what is the case and what specific purpose they are using mongoDB in their django project.

Why can't those feature can't be achieved by postgresql or redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `mongoDB` and `redis` are **Non-Relational** (No-SQL) Databases.
- `postgresql` is a **Relational** (SQL) Database.

Choosing the type of DB depends on people's requirements.

**SQL Databases**

> *SQL databases are known as relational databases, and have a table-based data structure, with a strict, predefined schema required.
>
>
>
> Eg: Oracle, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and **PostgreSQL***

**No-SQL Databases**

> *NoSQL databases, or non-relational databases, can be document based, graph databases, key-value pairs, or wide-column stores. NoSQL databases don’t require any predefined schema, allowing you to work more freely with “unstructured data.”
>
>
>
> Examples:
>
> Document: **MongoDB** and CouchDB
>
> Key-value: **Redis** and DynamoDB
>
> Wide-column: Cassandra and HBase
>
> Graph: Neo4j and Amazon Neptune.*

*What is the case and what specific purpose they are using mongoDB in their django project?*

> There are many reasons for that.
> I suggest you to read this to know why and in what cases people choose No-SQL DBs over Relational DBs - [No-SQL vs Relational DBs](https://www.mongodb.com/scale/nosql-vs-relational-databases)